# How can I vertical align my <li> to the top of this box which uses `display: flex`?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have boxes that contain unordered lists in HTML. I am using `display: flex` to help format the possible overflow of the `<ul>`. My CSS makes it so that if `<li>` elements don't fit in the box that no part of them will show (not just a clipped top off or similar like you might usually see with `overflow: hidden`.

The problem I have is, when there are only 1 or 2 `<li>` elements in the box, the element is vertically aligned to the center. I want it to align to the top.

[image: image if fiddle]

How can I achieve this? I have experimented with adding padding/margin to the `<ul>` as well as changing the height but I can't get it to work.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/zgwL0j22/1/

**CSS:**

```
.box {
    width: 350px;
    min-width: 350px;
    float: left;
    margin: 8px 16px 8px 0;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 15px;
}
ul {
    height: 90px;
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 15px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 0;
}
li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
li:before {
    content:'\2022';
    position: absolute;
    left: -5px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
    <ul>
        <li>Seth Rollins</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <ul>
        <li>List item</li>
        <li>A very long item that takes up two lines (at least I hope so)</li>
        <li>Another list item that takes up at least one line(trust me on this)</li>
        <li>This will not show</li>
        <li>This will not show</li>
        <li>This will not show</li>
        <li>List item</li>
        <li>List item</li>
        <li>List item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You have already used the `overflow:hidden;` then I think if you remove the `display:flex;` , it still well formatted.

Comment: @yong wu No, if I do that, then it will sometimes display the top half or so of some words. Like if it can only fit half of the `<li>`, it will only show half of it. That looks messy. I use `display: flex` so that if all of the bullet can't fit, it doesn't show any of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flex-start` property for `justify-content` or remove `justify-content` because `flex-start` is default value for this attribute.

Jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/zgwL0j22/2/

Comment: Oh god, I forgot I had put that property in there. Works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use space-around an after element on ul could break it. But where would be the point to use it ?

```css
.box {
    width: 350px;
    min-width: 350px;
    float: left;
    margin: 8px 16px 8px 0;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 15px;
}
ul {
    height: 90px;
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 15px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 0;
}
li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
li:before {
    content:'\2022';
    position: absolute;
    left: -5px;
}
ul:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  flex:1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <ul>
        <li>Seth Rollins</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <ul>
        <li>List item</li>
        <li>A very long item that takes up two lines (at least I hope so)</li>
        <li>Another list item that takes up at least one line(trust me on this)</li>
        <li>This will not show</li>
        <li>This will not show</li>
        <li>This will not show</li>
        <li>List item</li>
        <li>List item</li>
        <li>List item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

remove space-around ?

```css
.box {
    width: 350px;
    min-width: 350px;
    float: left;
    margin: 8px 16px 8px 0;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 15px;
}
ul {
    height: 90px;
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 15px;
    /*justify-content: space-around;*/
    margin: 0;
}
li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
li:before {
    content:'\2022';
    position: absolute;
    left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <ul>
        <li>Seth Rollins</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <ul>
        <li>List item</li>
        <li>A very long item that takes up two lines (at least I hope so)</li>
        <li>Another list item that takes up at least one line(trust me on this)</li>
        <li>This will not show</li>
        <li>This will not show</li>
        <li>This will not show</li>
        <li>List item</li>
        <li>List item</li>
        <li>List item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

or use a class to reset `justify-content` ?

```css
.box {
    width: 350px;
    min-width: 350px;
    float: left;
    margin: 8px 16px 8px 0;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 15px;
}
ul {
    height: 90px;
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 15px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 0;
}
.start ul {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  }
li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
li:before {
    content:'\2022';
    position: absolute;
    left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box start">
    <ul>
        <li>Seth Rollins</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <ul>
        <li>List item</li>
        <li>A very long item that takes up two lines (at least I hope so)</li>
        <li>Another list item that takes up at least one line(trust me on this)</li>
        <li>This will not show</li>
        <li>This will not show</li>
        <li>This will not show</li>
        <li>List item</li>
        <li>List item</li>
        <li>List item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```